# GDAL Appending Shapefile to SQL Error: Ogr2ogr ERROR 1: MSSQL extents query returned a NULL value

Tags: gdal, shapefile, ogr, sql-server

I have an OGR2OGR script to append a shapefile to an existing SQL table, but I get the error 'Ogr2ogr ERROR 1: MSSQL extents query returned a NULL value'. I have seen discussions with various solutions but none have worked for me.
In the script below I have to rename two fields in the shapefile first to match the corresponding fields in SQL, but there are no other fields I want to bring across, apart from the actual geometry of course. Does the Shapefile need to have the same fields as the SQL table or does it just need some to match names/type? GDAL version is 2.4.4.

```
ogrinfo [shapefile name] -sql "ALTER TABLE %FILENAME% RENAME COLUMN ZoneOver_1 TO Zone_Code"

ogrinfo [shapefile name] -sql "ALTER TABLE %FILENAME% RENAME COLUMN AmendmentN TO Amd_Num"

ogr2ogr --config GDAL_DRIVER_PATH [driver path] -append -f MSSQLSpatial -s_srs "EPSG:28355" "MSSQL:server=[server name];database=[database name];trusted_connection=yes" "[shapefile]" -lco "GEOM_NAME=GEOMETRY" -t_srs "EPSG:28355" -nln [SQL table to append to]
```

Comment: It may be a problem with the MSSQL/ODBC driver.  A more recent driver seems to fix this particular error for some people as documented at:  https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/3140 (this may not be an option for your old version of GDAL, though).

Comment: You can avoid the need to rename the fields beforehand, by using the `-fieldmap` option in conjunction with the `-append` option.  Check out the `-fieldmap` parameter for ogr2ogr, documented at: https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html .  there is an example of its use at the very end of the page, too.

Comment: I do not think that renaming the fields has any role. The error is `MSSQL extents query returned a NULL value` and I guess that before appending data GDAL needs to know the extents of the existing data. I can't say if NULL here means an error or if the table is empty and extent is really NULL. I do not know if the data that is appended must contain all the same attributes but you can test it easily if you will get the append to work at all.